# localhost replies with CANNOT GET/

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, localhost

This is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('website'));

const port = 8000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('the server is up and running');
    console.log(`in a localhost ${port}`);
})
```

and i linked it to html page which has the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
    
    
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        
        <title> Hello World!</title>
        
        
        
        <script src='L2Server.js' >  </script>

    </head>

    <body>

<p>Hi!</p>



<script src='L2Server.js' ></script>
    </body>

  





</html>
```

and when I run the code in the terminal it show that the server is up and running then when I open the localhost in the browser it displays a message with the following "CANNOT GET/" and I tried almost everything to solve this problem but i don't know what is the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route like

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // set response here
});
```

or provide static content from a folder

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

In your case place your html code in `./public/index.html` and provide it as static content.

Comment: i used this app.use(express.static('website'));
is it what do you mean cuz i already typed it in the code and i tried the method above and it didnt work

Comment: You have to provide an absolute path to a directory. `__dirname + '/public'` creates an absolute path relative to your .js file.
`__dirname` is the path of the directory containing your .js file.

Comment: sorry, but can you show me an example of a code because I don't understand the plus sign in the middle of the sentence you wrote should I write it in the code?
and if you can just show me an example

Comment: The `+` sign concatenates two strings. `__dirname + '/public'` creates a string containing the absolut path to the public folder, created relativ to your .js file. If you have a folder 'yourproject' containing your .js file and a subdirectory 'public' this will provide the contents of 'public' as static content. Now put your html file (`test.html`) in the public folder and navigate to `http://localhost:3000/test.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('website');
});
```

where 'website' is the name of your html

Comment: my html file called index and when i did what you are reffering to it displayed the word index and didnt execute whats in the file of the html which i published the code of it above

Comment: when i do it but with the sendFile method and do it with the absolute path of the file its shows this messagea and some more fellow errors "TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"

Comment: have you tried:
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('website', { root: '.' });
    });